# Mobile phones unable to connect to new bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mobile-phone, wds

I'm a relative noob at networking and I'm running into some trouble trying to use a TP-Link Archer C9 (AC1900) to share out the internet connection from my AT&T Nighthawk LTE wireless router. The house I live in only has LTE service for internet and the Nighthawk router's wifi signal is pretty weak. Hoping to use the TP-Link as the main network within our house and to act as a bridge to amplify the internet connection from the AT&T hotspot.

I've got it mostly working as my PCs and Macbook can connect and work just fine. I can't for the life of me get my phones to connect successfully though.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Followed these instructions to enable WDS bridging on the 2.4ghz frequency: http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-1083.html
- Both 2.4ghz and 5ghz are active on the TP-Link, however, the WDS bridging is set up on the 2.4ghz frequency.
- Set the Nighthawk router to run 2.4ghz only (I'd prefer to leave 5ghz on as well but I was running into more problems when both were enabled).

So where I'm at is that I can connect any computer (2 PCs and a Macbook) to the TP-LINK 2.4ghz SSID and it works! Yay.

However, I can't connect my mobile phones (Samsung Galaxy S8+) to the TP-Link network (either 2.4ghz or 5ghz). It fails to connect with a "Failed to obtain IP address" error message.

If I "Forget network" and then re-connect but specify "advanced options" and set the IP, gateway, etc. manually then I CAN connect, but I get the "Internet may not be available message" and I have no connectivity.

I'd like to be able to connect my phones as it's a requirement for some of the home networking setups that I want to do (the phone/setup app needs to be on the same network as the device, which I want to connect to the TP-Link router).

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the phones with PC's turned off? The number of connections may have been exceeded.

Comment: I did, actually. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might try disabling the Randomized MAC Address setting that seems to be gaining popularity for phones. That fixed it for me by disabling it on a Google Pixel phone with a WDS TP-Link router.